# Why does the TOP function not function as I expect in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I thought I knew how the TOP function works, but with this code below I'm not sure.

Please can someone tell me why it returns fruit:b ordinal:9, instead of the expected fruit:b ordinal:8?

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
 SELECT fruit, ordinal, row_number() OVER (
   ORDER BY (
     SELECT 1
     )
   ) AS rn
 FROM (
  VALUES (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c'), (5, 'c'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'a'), (8, 'b'), (9, 'b')
  ) fruits(ordinal, fruit)
 ), CTE2
AS (
 SELECT fruit, ordinal
 FROM cte AS cteouter
 WHERE rn = 1
  OR fruit != (
   SELECT fruit
   FROM cte AS cteinner
   WHERE cteinner.rn = cteouter.rn - 1
   )
 )
--SELECT * FROM CTE2
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM cte2
ORDER BY ordinal DESC
```

Comment: Interesting. `TOP (1)` to `TOP (8)` all include `{b;9}`. Starting from `TOP (9)` it disappears. `TOP (X) PERCENT` does not return `{b;9}` for any `X`.

Comment: It has to come down to the `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))`. It does not guarantee stable numbering of the `VALUES` rows. Apparently you happen to get a different sort order with TOP1-TOP8.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, edit your post tags to include it. If you're using any other DBMS that supports top, make sure to include it in your post tags.

Comment: @GSerg you are correct, thank you. feel free to move commend to answer accordingly.

Comment: Wherever you picked up that trick of using `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` you've been led astray. Try using plain old `ORDER BY 1` and *read the message* that the SELECT trick has been used to *hide* rather than deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` (as well as `over (order by 1)` or `over (order by 1/0)`) does not guarantee stable reproducible numbering of the incoming rows. Quite opposite, it effectively switches off the `order by` clause and makes it random.

When you run the top query with `TOP 1`, you get one execution plan, and when without `TOP`, you get another. These plans happen to randomly result in a different ordering of the rows in `CTE`, which in turn changes which rows are returned from `CTE2`.